# How to increment existing arrays length on click of add button

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I have ADD Button which has to increment items array length and display two fields which are "name" and "quantity".

So onChange of any of the fields, I am pushing the item details in items array.

```
 items = [ {name: "item 1", quantity: 1}, {name: "item 2", quantity: 1} ];
```

At first, items array will be empty. On click of ADD button, it should increment arrays length and after that set default value of quantity as 1.

I am not getting, how to implement add() for incrementing arrays length and setting default value of quantity.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: WHat is app?? more code.. react jquery ?? what is the code

Comment: Please simple code.. to explain, what u have done

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: _"it should increment arrays length and after that set default value of quantity as 1"_ you mean setting the value of field `quantity` to all the items in the array ?

Comment: @xdeepakv I am using react

Comment: @Alan Nunes yes , you are correct. After incrementing, it should set the default value for quantity as 1

Comment: @Nirmal Please check the answer. It should be simple.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
let counter = 1
let items = []

function setNewItem() {
    items.push({name: `item ${counter}`, quantity: 1})
    counter++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.push` does not create a new array after adding the value. You can test this in your browser console:

```js
let arr = []
let arrCopy = arr

arr.push(1) // [1]
arr === arrCopy // true

arr = [...arr, 2] // [1, 2]
arr === arrCopy // false
```

As React uses `===` internally to compare states and decide to re-render, if you use arr.push({ name: "item 3", quantity: 1 }), the UI will NOT be updated. You need to instead, every time the button is pressed (handling the onClick event), create a new array copying the old values and add the new one.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed, You can create a method and add in the existing array and set back the component state.

```
class SomeComponent {
  constructor(){
    this.state.products =[]
  }
  onAddProduct(item) {
    this.setState({
      products: this.state.products.concat({name: item, quantity: 1})
    })
  }
  onAddProductByName(name) {
    this.setState({
      products: this.state.products.map(item => {
        if(item.name === name) item.quantity +=1 
        return item
      })
    })
  }
}
```